# Should I use https for static files (images, css)

Tags: performance, file, https, static

I use https protocol for my login, registration, admin pages of my web app.
If I don't write some htaccess rule, all my static files images, css, js, ect. are loaded through https too.
Does this decrease the performance of my app and is it better to use http for all static resources of my app?

Comment: Hello. In order to make a decision, you have to measure the performance and see if there are acceptable or not. If the performance are not too bad, i advise you keep https, since it increase privacy of your communication with your clients.

Comment: Resources for HTML documents served via HTTPS should always also be served that way. Browsers may otherwise decide to either emit a warning or not load the insecure resource at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you attempt to include a static file over `HTTP` while the original dynamic page was served through `HTTPS` the browser might emit a warning that this webpage is trying to server non secure content over a secure channel. So you should avoid doing that. There's of course a penalty from serving a resource over `HTTPS` but static files are usually cached by browsers so that shouldn't be that much of a problem. Also you might consider minifying and combining your scripts into a single one in order to reduce the number of HTTP(S) requests made to the server. That's where you will gain most.

For your images you might also consider using a technique called [`CSS sprites`](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).